# Firebase upload-sym file error

Tags: xcode8, firebase-crash-reporting

I am facing a strange compiler error in `upload-sym` file which is used for firebase crash reporting platform. I am using the latest update from `FirebaseCrash 2.0.0`.

Please check out this photo in xCode 8.3.2:

[image]

I tried cleaning the build path, clean, build,research online for some kind of solution but it seems to be I'm the first one who has faced it.